# How set the same CookieStore for SWT browser and Jetty HttpClient

Tags: java, cookies, browser, swt, jetty-httpclient

Since a `java.net.CookieStore` manages cookies in `org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient`, I want to share the cookies with the SWT `Browser` widget.

HttpClient and Browser are both Eclipse technologies. Is there a way to have the same cookie store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot share the Cookie stores of HttpClient and SWT Browser. The Browser control uses the cookie store of the underlying native Browser, e.g. Mozilla, WebKit of IE.

You may want to try `Browser::setCookie()` and `getCookie()` to store and retrieve specific SWT cookies. The changes apply to all `Browser` control instances within an SWT application.

Comment: If the `org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser` uses `java.net.CookieStore`, or exposes an implementation of `java.net.CookieStore`, then Eclipse Jetty Client can use it.

Comment: Note, that the SWT browser control **does not** use `java.net.CookieStore`.As outlined in the answer, it uses its own cookie store.